# Querydsl limit record example

Tags: spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I need to select limit record by `querydsl`, my query is like:

```
select *from <table> where <column_id> = 5 limit 2
```

How can I do a query in my repository interface method to the given above query?

Answer (score 3):

Use `QueryDslPredicateExecutor.findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable)` and then get the actual results back using `PageRequest.of(0, limit)`.